# Initialize nested json using Typescript and Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I am doing a POST request by sending an object but I get an error error

> TypeError: Can not set property 'ItemCode' of undefined

I'm using Angular 7 with typescript

This is my initialize Json

```
    objEnvio:any = <any> {
        DocumentLines:<any>[]
    };
```

This is my code:

```
    Cadastrar() {
        var today = new Date();
        var self = this;
        this.objEnvio.CardCode = something;
        this.objEnvio.DocDueDate = something;
            this.objEnvio.BPL_IDAssignedToInvoice = something;
            $('.table-servico .mat-row').each(function(index, element){
                     self.objEnvio.DocumentLines[index].ItemCode =something;   // this line is throwing the error
```

Expected result:

```
   {
       "CardCode": "C000009",
       "DocDueDate": "2019-04-25",
       "BPL_IDAssignedToInvoice": 1,
       "DocumentLines": [
          {
          "ItemCode": "IT0001",
          "UnitPrice": 207,
          "Quantity": 4,
          "TaxCode": "1101-001",
          },
          {
          "ItemCode": "SV0003",
          "UnitPrice": 110,
          "Quantity": 1,
          "TaxCode": "1933-001",
          },
         ]
     }
```

Current actual result:

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'ItemCode' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

now works, just add another

```
   objEnvio:any = <any>{
            DocumentLines:<any>[
                 <any>{

               }
          ]
        };
```